# Full image OR 1px pattern?

Tags: iphone

in my iPhone app I would to create a ThemeManager in order to skin the view.
I am wondering what is the best way to limit memory use.

I would like to fill a view with a background.
Should I load a 1px pattern and draw it into the view or should I load the complete image ?

Thanks for you comments.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

A 1px pattern sounds like you could use a plain color. But anyway, when you're optimizing:

1. measure
2. optimize
3. measure

instead of just optimize.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1. measure 2. optimize 3. goto 1? :)

Comment: @LiraNuna My recipe was meant for people who start with "2. optimize", so I rather not used control flow statements. Also, your proposal is missing a break condition. You'll be optimizing the rest of your life ;)

Comment: I was talking about 1  px height but 320 px width